# Execute NuGet Pacakage Manager Console Command from post build event

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, post-build-event

I have **nuget package manager** command..

```
( Get-Project -All | ? { $_.ProjectName } | % { Get-Package
-ProjectName $_.ProjectName } ) | Sort -Unique | % { $_ | select id, 
version, title, Description, requireLicenseAcceptance, licenseurl, 
projecturl } | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a | Out-File D:\licenses\NugetPackages.html
```

This command retrieves information about nuget package install in project and creates a html file of it.

I want to execute this command in post built event.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run a PowerShell command that uses the NuGet Package Manager Console in a post build event.

Post build events are run by MSBuild so it needs to work when the build is run from the command line.

An alternative approach would be to write a console app that uses NuGet.Core.dll to do the same thing that the PowerShell script is doing.